# How do I find missing schema fields on a Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I add new fields directly to my MongoDB database and I forget to add them to my Mongoose schema, how can I alert myself to the problem without it failing silently.

The following example shows that all fields are returned from a query (regardless of the schema) but undefined if you access the key.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var user_conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://db/user');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  // location: String,
  admin: Boolean
});
var User = user_conn.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOne({email: 'foo@bar.com.au'}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc.email);
  console.log(doc.location);
});
```

Result:

```
{ _id: 57ce17800c6b25d4139d1f95,
  email: 'foo@bar.com.au',
  location: 'Australia',
  admin: true,
  __v: 0 }      // <-- console.log(doc);

foo@bar.com.au  // <-- console.log(doc.email);

undefined       // <-- console.log(doc.location);
```

I could read each doc key and throw an error if undefined, but is this the only way?

**Versions**
Node.js: 6.5.0
Mongoose: 4.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from Amiram's answer.  I now use [lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to get the object during a query but when I need to update or save it still looks up the schema.

```
User.findOne({email: 'foo@bar.com.au'}).lean().exec(function (err, doc) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc.email);
  console.log(doc.location);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `strict` to `false` on the schema so it will save all properties even if they are not in schema:

```js
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  admin: Boolean
}, {strict: false});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

In order to get a property which is not in schema you need to use `doc.toObject()` and use the returned object, or to use `doc.get('location')`

Comment: Added the strict option but still getting undefined

Comment: Thank you Amiram, the toObject() worked perfectly!  That is the answer so please remove the strict option and I will award the answer.

Comment: I think the strict is still needed. If you won't add it, when you save back the doc you'll lose all non-schema properties.

Comment: But when you save, the mongoose promise will throw an error so I will add the schema entry.  I'm not worried about query but I do want save errors.

Comment: Are you sure it will throw error if you have a non-schema property in save? I didn't see an error for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122722/discussion-between-shane-davies-and-amiram-korach).